# Can`t find the right screen resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 afterwards, I noticed that my screen resolution is not matching properly. Jumped to scree display settings and found that the only resolution option is "1024x768(4:3)" while my laptop screen is 1366x1768.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler LE [Radeon HD 6610M/7610M] [1002:6742] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Radeon HD 7610M [1179:fb31]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's your Toshiba model number?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix What the difference?. It is the AMD VCARD issue no longer supported since 16.04.

Comment: Support for AMD was added to kernels after 4.4 you can google the changes to see what was done and compare it to your model.